# Why do they name a program “mogrify” in Imagemagick?

Tags: terminology, naming, imagemagick

I am not a native English speaker. Is there some trick in this name? What does it mean or imply?

PS. I don't know whether this is the right SE site to post this question but if it is not could you indicate me?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about naming something, and not about a conceptual programming topic.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would maybe agree if you'd clarify what is that _something_ you are talking about. As stated, your close reason feels too broad to apply, think eg about a role naming plays in API design

Comment: @gnat See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/2382

Comment: That makes good sense, thanks. So, we object to question being about naming of particular, specific class or a method, as being of too limited interest, right? As opposed to questions about [proper term for a concept](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/2382/31260)...

Comment: @gnat: There are general principles for naming, like prefixing interfaces with I.  I'm happy to talk about that.  But picking specific names, or asking why something was named as it was, is completely uninteresting (to me, anyway), especially one that is [easily answered with a Google search](https://www.google.com/#q=what+does+mogrify+mean).

Comment: @RobertHarvey agree. Count me in close voters for this question :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From [transmogrify](http://www.google.com/search?q=transmogrify) - "transform, especially in a surprising or magical manner"

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4n40.png]

Comment: Yeah Calvin 'n Hobbes!

Comment: @Michael, great comic.  I was going to answer with that.

Answer (score 8):

A visual explanation of the origins of the term at [AMAT page on Transmogrification](http://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/def_en/kap_5/illustr/i5_1_4.html) seems appropriate:

> Changing something into something else the easy way (without much effort and painlessly, of course) is an old dream of everybody...
>
> - Here is a present day expression of the need to dream about **transmogrification** from one of my favorite books dealing about children and how to raise them:
>     [image: http://www.google.com/imgres?hl=en&sa=X&biw=1918&bih=908&tbm=isch&prmd=imvns&tbnid=AlJIxoOqXZyVoM:&imgrefurl=http://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/def_en/kap_5/illustr/i5_1_4.html&docid=r5LxPg7TlObFmM&imgurl=http://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/def_en/kap_5/illustr/transmogrification.gif&w=578&h=603&ei=gX06T7PdA4Ps0gGssfTFCw&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=406&sig=109570079625149764910&page=1&tbnh=133&tbnw=127&start=0&ndsp=52&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0&tx=80&ty=52]
>
> Well, a working version of a transmogrifier has not been invented yet. So if you really want to change yourself into a person who knows about defects in crystals, you must still do it the hard way!

Comment: The word predates Calvin and Hobbes by at least a few years:  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/transmogrify.